# Filter Arrow Function (ES6)

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6

Not sure how to exactly use this .filter() with an arrow function.

Instructions:

Use the built in filter method to filter over the jobs array of objects and return the object of the person with a job as a programmer. Make sure to use the arrow function in conjunction with the filter method.

Tried Solution:

```
var jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];

var solution = jobs.filter(person => person === "programmer");
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask for solutions to homework questions.

Comment: Sadly, it's becoming increasingly so

Comment: @PBandJ333 I've added answer for you. Is that helped you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by many ways e.g by using [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), using [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and so on. But If I were you I'll try this way using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the
>   object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to
>   inheriting it).

```js
var jobs = [{
    receptionist: "James"
  },
  {
    programmer: "Steve"
  },
  {
    designer: "Alicia"
  }
];

var solution = jobs.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('programmer'));
console.log(solution)
```

With `in`:

```
var jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];

var solution = jobs.filter(obj => 'programmer' in obj);
console.log(solution)
```

With `includes`:

```
var jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];

var solution = jobs.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).includes('programmer'));
console.log(solution)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the *keys* of the object (or, in this case, just the single key) to see if it matches `'programmer'`.

```js
const jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
        {programmer: "Steve"},
        {designer: "Alicia"}];
const match = jobs.find((job) => job.hasOwnProperty('programmer'));
console.log(match);
```

But this is a *pretty weird* object structure. If you can, try refactoring your code such that your object is something like the following, to make it easier to iterate over:

```js
const jobs = [{
    title: 'receptionist',
    name: "James"
  },
  {
    title: 'programmer',
    name: "Steve"
  },
  {
    title: 'designer',
    name: "Alicia"
  }
];
const match = jobs.find(({title}) => title === 'programmer');
console.log(match);
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, `hasOwnProperty` makes more sense

Comment: I'd prefer `job => "programmer" in job`

Answer (score 2):

What `filter` needs is a boolean return value that tells it that a particular element satisfies the condition and should be filtered out.

Here, `hasOwnProperty` does return a boolean value and this acts as a return value for your arrow function for `filter`.

```js
const jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];

const solution = jobs.filter(person => person.hasOwnProperty("programmer"));

console.log(solution);
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly use the `return` keyword if the arrow function's body has only one line.

For eg, the following code is equivalent to the above snippet.

```
jobs.filter((person)=>{return person.hasOwnProperty("programmer")})
```

Comment: This answers my question perfectly thank you! I completely forgot about the .hasOwnProperty function.

Comment: Great! Keep learning. :)

Answer (score -2):

> var solution = jobs.filter(person => person === "programmer");

That's the same as:

```
var solution = jobs.filter(function(person) {
    return (person === "programmer" ? true : false);
});
```

Where person is an element in the jobs array. Now answer this yourself: is the following condition true for your desired solution?

```
{ title: 'programmer', name: "Steve"} === "programmer"
```